# Look up GWT CellTable header style/s?

Tags: gwt, celltable, gwt-celltable

How can TH style name/s of a GWT CellTable's heading be looked up programatically?

I have looked at the Client Bundle documentation but it isn't immediately obvious to me how it all fits together. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Not sure exactly what you want to do when accessing the TH style names.

If you want to override the standard css style of a celltable header, here are some of the css styles you can override to change the Look and Feel of the component.

```
.cellTableFirstColumnHeader {}

.cellTableLastColumnHeader {}

.cellTableHeader {
      border-bottom: 2px solid #6f7277;
      padding: 3px 15px;
      text-align: left;
      color: #4b4a4a;
      text-shadow: #ddf 1px 1px 0;
      overflow: hidden;
 }

.cellTableSortableHeader {
  cursor: pointer;
  cursor: hand;
}

.cellTableSortableHeader:hover {
  color: #6c6b6b;
}

.cellTableSortedHeaderAscending {

}

.cellTableSortedHeaderDescending {

}
```

Here is the complete list of styles for cellTables [CellTable.css](https://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/source/browse/trunk/user/src/com/google/gwt/user/cellview/client/CellTable.css)

Now if you want to access you header programmatically, you can use [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8189991/how-do-i-programmatically-get-info-about-a-celltables-headers/8213249#8213249) to get the TableSectionElement corresponding the the Header of your table. Then you can access the row, then the cells, and lookup for their styles I guess.

Last thing if you want to override the header style, maybe you can use the following method when adding your column to your table

```
public void addColumn(Column<T, ?> col, Header<?> header)
```

Then create your Header or use a TextHeader for example then set your style on it before adding it to the table using

```
public void setHeaderStyleNames(String styleNames)
```

Example

```
TextHeader textHeader = new TextHeader("headerTitle");
textHeader.setHeaderStyleNames("my-style");
myTable.addColumn(myColumn, textHeader);
```

Answer (score 0):

Easy solution:

```
import com.google.gwt.user.cellview.client.CellTable.Resources;

private String getCellTableHeaderStyle() {
    Resources res = GWT.create(Resources.class);
    return res.cellTableStyle().cellTableHeader();
}
```